# Do I need to I save intermediate subsets of data while building decision tree on spark recursively?

Tags: scala, recursion, machine-learning, apache-spark, decision-tree

I am building a Decision Tree on Scala/Spark (on a 50 node cluster). Since my dataset is somewhat big (~ 2TB), I want to parallelise it.
My code looks like this

```
def buildTree(data: RDD[Array[Double]], numInstances: Int): Node = {

    // Base case
    if (numInstances < minInstances) {
        return new Node(isLeaf = true)
    }

    /*
    * Find best split for all columns in data
    */

    val leftRDD = data.filter(leftSplitCriteria)
    val rightRDD = data.filter(rightSplitCriteria)
    val subset = Seq(leftRDD, rightRDD)
    val counts = Seq(numLeft, numRight)

    val children = (0 until 2).map(i =>
                    (i,subset(i),counts(i)))
                    .par.map(x => {buildTree(x._2,x._3)})

    return new Node(children(0), children(1), Split)
}
```

My questions are

1. Scala being a lazy language, doesn't immediately compute the output of map/filter operation. So while building a new Node, do all the filters of parents, and parents of parents, are stacked up (and recursively applied)?
2. What would be the best approach to build the tree in parallel? Should I cache/save the dataset in the intermediate steps?
3. While running this code, is it sufficient to just provide **num-executers**, or would it make a difference if I give **executor-cores**, **driver-cores** etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up parallelising split finding at each level by features.

Refer

- http://zhanpengfang.github.io/418home.html
- http://tullo.ch/articles/speeding-up-decision-tree-training/

Answer (score 1):

1. I assume that the `numLeft` is computed using `leftRDD.count()` and counting is an action and will force the computation of all the dependent RDDs.
2. You will actually make more than once the filtering in this case, once for the count and another time for each children dependence. You should cache your RDD to avoid double computation and you only need the last one so you can `unpersist` the previous one at every stage.

See [Apache Spark Method returning an RDD (with Tail Recursion)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29565857/apache-spark-method-returning-an-rdd-with-tail-recursion) for more explanation

Side note: Spark uses the lazy evaluation model, I think we don't say scala is a lazy language.

Comment: 1) numLeft is computed during _findBestSplit_ method.
2) Is caching such a good idea given the dataset is large?

Comment: 1) Are you doing any action on the RDD ? I think so from my experience with decision tree, you need at some point to count the instance on the right/left side or something like that. This action will evaluate the RDD
2) I think caching would help and is not harmful if you unpersist the data at each stage. Only if your cluster has enough memory, disk usage will be way to slow and you'd better recompute.

Comment: 1) Yes, RDD does get evaluated (few map-reduce operations). Please correct me if I am wrong - In that case, Spark would be able to take output of map operation of task that ran during findBestSplitMethod. 
2) I would be able to unpersist only after child has been computed right? In that case, again multiple copies of data are being created.

Comment: 1) What is not cached/persisted will be recomputed, a map operation does nothing (it's lazy) until an action is applied. And this map will be computed for every action except if cached. 
2) Right, you should have something like at most twice your dataset in memory at some point if you uncache things properly

Comment: Thanks for clearing up things. I guess I'll have to change my tree building approach from recursive to parallel node building at each depth level (something like http://zhanpengfang.github.io/418home.html)